# Android Transition Framework Backport?

Tags: android, transition

The new Android Transition framework available in Android 4.4 KitKat is by far one of the coolest things I've seen done for android in a long time. As a developer I've recently switched to developing for sdk 14 (ICS), which means I'm still years away from from using these awesome new features.

- [Android 4.4 KitKat Transitions](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-transitions)
- [Transitions DevBytes Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3H7nJ4QaD8)

Is there any news of anyone, or even Google themselves creating a backport for these awesome features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go! I've seen this out there and it seems to be the best option.

https://github.com/guerwan/TransitionsBackport

Comment: You said "this seems to be the best option out there" Are there other options?

Comment: Not that I've seen for the transition animations yet.

Answer (score 2):

I am author of more advanced backport of transitions framework. So just checkout github page and try it

https://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere

Almost all of usable functionality is already backported

Comment: In which was is this "more advanced"?

Comment: for example, all new transitions, improvements and another fixes from Android 5.0 and 6.0 is also backported